# How to set conditional classes in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand conditional variables using Reactjs. Using plain ol' HTML and jQuery, for instance, my code would look like so.

HTML:

```
<p class="aclass">Error</p>
<input id="dabox" type="text" />
<input id="dabutton" type="button" value="Ship It" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#dabutton').click(function(){
if ( $('#dabox').val()== "" ){
$('.aclass').addClass('error');
}
});
```

CSS:

```
.error {color: red;}
.aclass {//does nothing//}
```

I am having trouble understanding how to conditionally set the class using Reactjs. My best guess is something like so:

JavaScript

```
runcheck:function(){
if ( document.getElementById('dabox').value == 0 ){
var depends = "aclass error";
}
},

render:function(){
var depends = "aclass";
return (
<p className={depends}>Error</p>
<input onClick="runcheck()" type="submit"/>
)
}
```

Naturally the code doesn't work. How would I go about setting these variables conditionally using Reactjs?

Comment: forget the DOM, work with javascript, your app state is the source of truth

Comment: Seriously, you should watch some videos about React, how it works and why your syntax is wrong. Take some hours and dive into React, it will take some time, but after, you will get at least the basics of how data driven UIs* work, there is a lot to discover, like redux and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example illustrates some of the fundamental mindset changes you need when working with React. They're not difficult to grasp, for starters take a look at:

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html
- https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

And here's some code for you:

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
    /**
     * Component's current (internal) state
     */
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            text: '' // initial value for text input
        };
    },

    /**
     * Renders virtual DOM according to component's current state
     */
    render() {
        const showError = this.state.text == '';

        return <div>
            { showError
                    ? <p className='error'>Error</p>
                    : null
            }

            <input type='text' value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onChange} />
            <input type='button' onClick={this.onClick} value='Ship It' />
        </div>
    },

    /**
     * Every time the textbox is changed, this handler is called.
     * It simply updates the component's state
     */
    onChange(ev) {
        // State changes cause render to be re-evaluated and your DOM will be updated accordingly.
        this.setState({ text: ev.target.value });
    },

    /**
     * When the button is clicked, this handler is called
     */
    onClick() {
        // ...
    }
});
```